# find date and time user last access database

Tags: sql-server, users

I need to find the last time a user accessed the database.  I am new to SQL and rarely have to use it.  Details would help or links to learn those details.

Comment: The options and syntax change with the type and version of the database.  What type  (MS SQL, Oracle, Postgres, etc) and version are you using?

Comment: MS SQL     Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      14.0.17254.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      14.0.1016.251
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.14393

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MS SQL server logins are not automatically tracked but this can be easily enabled with the [Common Criteria Compliance option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/common-criteria-compliance-enabled-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017).

From the link you would run this

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'common criteria compliance enabled', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE; 
GO
```

Then restart the database and run the scripts [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616319) from Microsoft.

The logins can be accessed with this query

```
Select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

You need elevated permissions (View Server State or higher) to query this table.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, most default configurations do not track successful SQL access.

There are a bunch of ways that you can start tracking, (*based on your configuration, as mentioned by @kevinsky in the comments.*)

You can look into to those to see if any have been implemented. If not...